# Using TFS Integration Tools, how can I skip migrating VC paths that have been deleted?

Tags: version-control, tfs, migration, tfsintegrationplatform

We are migrating WI & VC from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010. One of the projects uses a folder in VC for their branches of the solution. Over time, they delete branches that are no longer active or needed. We are not truly deleting them using the command line tools, but they are removed from our Source Control Explorer view.

When I migrate their source code, all the deleted folders are migrating too and becoming active (aka not deleted). How do I tell TFS Integration tool to ignore or skip the folders in source control that are deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is add a `<Filter Neglect="true">` to the session configuration. This works the same way as **Cloaking** does in a workspace mapping. There is a caveat that this can only be done for new session configurations.

[See this blog post for more information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/03/16/tfs-integration-platform-i-have-just-moved-my-vc-content-now-i-want-to-sync-from-a-specific-snapshot-now-what.aspx).

Here is a configuration file sample:

```
  <Filters>
     <FilterPair Neglect="true">
       <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="..<guid1>.." FilterString="$/serverpathtocloak" /> 
       <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="..<guid2>.." FilterString="$/serverpathtocloak" /> 
     </FilterPair>
   </Filters>
```